# Typography.com font not loaded in FF

Tags: html, css, fonts, typography

Im working on a site where I include a font from typography.com.

The nessecary file for the font is included as a css import:

```
@import 'https://cloud.typography.com/6741734/7240552/css/fonts.css'
```

And the font family is set as a variable like this:

```
$gotham = 'Gotham A', 'Gotham B' 

.body {
    font-family: $gotham;
}
```

The font is displayed and rendered correctly in the latest versions of Safari, Chrome and IE, however the font is not displayed in FF.

I am quite puzzled as to why this is happening, I have checked multiple versions of FF on different machines and the result is the same, the font is not loaded.

The page is [goingplaces.jackjones.com](http://goingplaces.jackjones.com)

Comment: Did you try to open your imported `.css` in your browser? It will give a 403. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Yeah if i try to go directly to the url of the imported css file I get a "403 forbidden", but this happens in every browser.

Comment: Did you buy this font? Maybe you need to host it on your own server.

Comment: I too cannot see how the font is rendering on any browser, given it returns a 403

Comment: Yes I am paying for the font, and I do have the possibility to put it on a server, but I was hoping to avoid that for now, since its already working in all the other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `@import` without `https:`.

Example:

```
@import "//cloud.typography.com/6741734/7240552/css/fonts.css";
```

This should do it.

---

Solution was seen on [How Cloud.typography Works](http://www.typography.com/cloud/how-it-works/).